# The deployment of eclipse_che failed in kubernetes in multi user mode

Tags: kubernetes, eclipse-che

I use the helm installation provided at https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/kubernetes-multi-user.html with the custom values below :

```
global:
  cheNamespace: "bmap"
  multiuser: true
  serverStrategy: "single-host"
  ingressDomain: eclipseche.mydomain.com
  cheWorkspacesNamespace: bmap
```

the pod "postgress" start after a while.
the pod "keycloak" needs to be restarted because of the timeout with postgress

the pod "che" needs to be restarted because of the timeout of postgress and keycloak.
After restart,  the pod "che" is still not running with the error in the "che" pod

```
2018-11-26 14:34:02,139[ost-startStop-1] [ERROR] [butedRemoteSubscriptionStorage 58] - Unable to create distributed event subscriptions map.
java.net.BindException: no port available in range [7800 .. 7850] (bind_addr=/fe80:0:0:0:4031:65ff:fe25:6b55%eth0)
```

How to solved this problems in a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: This is JGroups complaining that it cant bind TCP port. Make sure nothing blocks this range (7800-7850). Or you can change it on api.war/WEB-INF/classes/jgroups/che-tcp.xml but this will require to rebuild the image locally.

Comment: Do you know how is it possible to open these ports in a kubernetes cluster no just locally.